# I'm unable to build with XCode8.1 on travis CI

Tags: xcode, travis-ci

I have [a job](https://travis-ci.org/adi2004/super-memo2-pod)  which is set up with `"osx_image": "xcode8.1"`, but when it starts it uses `Xcode 7.3.1` and the build fails because it the code is written in Swift 3.

Any ideea why this happens?

BTW: it is my first time using Travis and it's amazing how easy is to set it up :)

Comment: Xcode 7.3 is not supporting swift 3.0 so it gives the error.

Comment: I know, that's the problem. But I specify what image to use and it doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apperently adding:

```
os: osx
xcode_project: "Example/ADISuperMemo2.xcodeproj"
```

to `.travis.yml` file, made the build possible.